# What does the M1-3 and MR keys mean?

Tags: keyboard

With my Logitech G105 Gaming Keyboard (http://support.logitech.com/en_us/product/gaming-keyboard-g105) There are several buttons at the top, M1-M3 and MR. What do they mean and do? I do know what G1-G6 do though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [quickstart guide](http://www.logitech.com/assets/42320/6/g105-quick-start-guide.pdf):

> M-keys—Each M-key extends the capability of the G-keys, allowing you
>   to assign up to 3 different key configurations to each profile for
>   your G-keys. This allows you to react to different game scenarios in a
>   single profile by switching between the M1, M2 and M3 keys.
>
> MR-key—Use this key to record quick macros. For instructions, see
>   Recording a quick macro in this guide